# querydsl: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TREATED_PATH

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

springboot version is 2.51,
java vsersion 1.8
it will crash in selectFrom(),
erro info: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TREATED_PATH

how to resolve it,i cant find a way in web

there is my code

```
@SpringBootTest
class Demo4ApplicationTests {
    @Resource
    private BmsPostRepository bm;
    @Autowired
    private JPAQueryFactory queryFactory;
    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        var tab="hot";
        var page = PageRequest.of(pageNo, pageSize);
        var t = QBmsPost.bmsPost;
        var u = QUmsUser.umsUser;
        var now = new Date();
        var tomorrow = DateUtils.addDays(now, 1);
        var query = queryFactory
                .selectFrom(t)
                .leftJoin(u)
                .on(t.userId.eq(u.id));
        if (tab.equals("hot")) query = query.where(t.createTime.lt(tomorrow));
        var re = (!tab.equals("hot")) ?
                query.orderBy(t.createTime.desc()) :
                query.orderBy(t.view.desc(), t.createTime.desc());
        var er =re.fetch();
    }

}
```

there is dependency

```
    <dependency>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.M1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.M1</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TREATED_PATH

    at com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLTemplates.<init>(JPQLTemplates.java:147)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLTemplates.<init>(JPQLTemplates.java:51)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLTemplates.<clinit>(JPQLTemplates.java:46)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAProvider.<clinit>(JPAProvider.java:59)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAQuery.<init>(JPAQuery.java:48)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAQueryFactory.query(JPAQueryFactory.java:138)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAQueryFactory.select(JPAQueryFactory.java:72)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAQueryFactory.selectFrom(JPAQueryFactory.java:102)
    at com.example.demo.Demo4ApplicationTests.contextLoads(Demo4ApplicationTests.java:31
```

BmsPost.java

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have mixed versions of querydsl. I guess you are having querydsl-core version 4.4.x while your querydsl-jpa is of version 5.0.0.M1.
(this is probably caused by a spring-boot starter library.)

Anyhow, this can easily fixed by explicitely adding the correct version of querydsl-core as dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.M1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Small note, querydsl release version 5.0.0, so better to use it instead of 5.0.0.M1.